# 2d 3*3 LED matrix code error

Tags: arduino-uno

I have  written a trivial code in Arduino IDE but while verifying its returning a error displaying "i was not declared in scope 12'

```
  int pinMatrix[i][j]= {{2,3,4},{5,6,7},{7,8,9}};
void setup() {
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    pinMode(pinMatrix[i][j],OUTPUT);
  }
}

}

void loop() {
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  for(j=0;j<3;j++){
      digitalWrite(pinMatrix[i][j],HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(pinMatrix[i][j],LOW);
  }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `i` & `j` are not declared. They should be declared as 3. Try this:

```
const int x = 3;
const int y = 3;

int pinMatrix[x][y] = {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, {7, 8, 9}};

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      pinMode(pinMatrix[i][j], OUTPUT);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      digitalWrite(pinMatrix[i][j], HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(pinMatrix[i][j], LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried it , it ain't working and is returning the same error

Comment: Try it again, the code I posted, and post the FULL eror message.

Comment: Thanks!!                                                                                                      yeah by mistake i wasn't reading the full error message , now i read it and i made the changes, the code is running now

Comment: Please accept the answer if this answer helped you. It means that this question is resolved and needs no further attention.